# d3.json and servlet doGet request

Tags: json, servlets, get, d3.js

I want to dynamically visualize the output of some java code with d3 by passing json from a servlet via doGet request...

I know I can do an HTTP request with d3 by doing this...

```
d3.json("data.js", function(data) { alert(data.length) });
```

However, I want to update the visualization every second. Would the calling the callback function do another request and receive a new json object or would it just use the json I received the first time?

I was planning on using a js timer to request the new json every second or so...wanted to see if I could receive the updated json using the callback function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `d3.json(<url>, <callback>)` performs an asynchronous request. So you would need to call this around once every second:

```
setInterval(function() {
  d3.json(<url>, <callback>);
}, 1000);
```

However, if the server is slow to respond, this could cause a backlog of requests to build up. Instead, you could request more data every time you receive it:

```
fetch();
function fetch() {
  d3.json("more.json", function(json) {
    // Update visualisation here…
    setTimeout(fetch, 1000); // fetch more data after 1000ms
  });
}
```

On the other hand, this will stop requesting data if there's an error response (since D3.js currently doesn't tell you if an error occurred). If you want to handle errors, you can use XMLHttpRequest directly.